Committing without passing Ruff checks
How can I commit to my branch while ignoring ruff errors. I am unable to commit with import errors for experimental code and it prevents me from checkpointing my code as I develop
Tried to run git commit -m "test", nothing gets commited and I am unable to push

What does this have to do with ruff errors and "monorepo"? To commit something, you first have to add it to the staging area. Did you do that?

Sounds like you should use -n when committing because the ruff check sounds like something that a commit hook is running.

What is a "ruff error"? Is it a pre-commit hook? Hooks can be ignored with git commit -n. But I assume the hooks are in place for a reason, so be aware that ignoring them might cause problems in the future.

I guess the reason the commit fails is because you have a pre-commit job (with ruff) configured? If that´s the case, the solution to your question is to execute first ´pre-commit uninstall´ before retrying to commit.
